# json schema to validate multiple types and values for one parameter

Tags: json, validation, schema

Please help me with this:
I try to write a json schema to validate the following object:

json object:

```
{"param":value}
```

Possible values: 'all', [array of any integers]

So it is a simple json object which contain one variable that could be string 'all', or array of any integers [].

I tried this but it doesn't work in json schema validator:

```
 { 
     "type": ["string","array"], 
     "items": { "oneOf":  [  
      "all", 
      { "type": "integer" } 
        ] 
     }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What JSON schema validator are you using?

Answer (score 5):

For draft4 this schema should work

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "param": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "enum": ["all"]
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {"type": "integer"}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["param"]
}
```

Value of `oneOf` should be list of objects and keyword `enum` allows to  compare with the value.